# By appending a picture to the list it will not find the page class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I have a problem with appending pictures in the list pictures that uses photoswipe. The jquery mobile page uses the class gallery-page that will open it in a nice viewer.
I try to add more pictures with the append function to the pictures list. 
This works fine only the problem is when I click on the image it will NOT open it in the nice viewer. 
I think this is something to do with the class gallery-page. In some way the added pictures by jquery can't find the class gallery-page.
What can I do?

This is how the page looks like:

Javascript in the HEAD:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
         * IMPORTANT!!!
         * REMEMBER TO ADD  rel="external"  to your anchor tags. 
         * If you don't this will mess with how jQuery Mobile works
         */

        (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('div.gallery-page')
                    .live('pageshow', function(e){

                        var 
                            currentPage = $(e.target),
                            options = {},
                            photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.gallery a", e.target).photoSwipe(options,  currentPage.attr('id'));

                        return true;

                    })

                    .live('pagehide', function(e){

                        var 
                            currentPage = $(e.target),
                            photoSwipeInstance = PhotoSwipe.getInstance(currentPage.attr('id'));

                        if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" && photoSwipeInstance != null) {
                            PhotoSwipe.detatch(photoSwipeInstance);
                        }

                        return true;

                    });

            });

        }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

    </script>
```

Page in the body:

```
    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="Gallery" class="gallery-page" >
        <div data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar"> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#spots" data-transition="none" data-direction="reverse"><img src="images/m1.png"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#addspots_page1" data-transition="none" data-direction="reverse"><img src="images/m2.png"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#internetspots" data-transition="none" data-direction="reverse"><img src="images/m3.png"/></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar --> 
        <h2>Extra information</h2> 
        </div><!-- /header -->


        <div data-role="content">   
        <ul class="gallery" id="pictures" >
        <!-- is necessery because photoswipe can't have null images -->
        <li class="s1"><a href="images/no_photo.jpg" rel="external"><img src="image1.jpeg" alt="Image 001" /></a><p>s1</li>
        </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Append picture with jquery:

```
    $("#pictures").append('<li class="s2"><a href="image2.jpeg" rel="external"><img src="image2.jpeg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>'</li>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `.photoSwipe` on the appended image:

```
$("#pictures")
    .append('<li class="s2"><a href="image2.jpeg" rel="external"><img src="image2.jpeg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>'</li>')
    .find("a").photoSwipe(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Is this a syntax error or just a mistake while posting your question

```
// extra single quote and closing tag next to the closing </li> element
$("#pictures").append('<li class="s2"><a href="image2.jpeg" rel="external"><img src="image2.jpeg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>'</li>')
```

Should be

```
$("#pictures").append('<li class="s2"><a href="image2.jpeg" rel="external"><img src="image2.jpeg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>')
```

> **Updating lists** If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the `refresh()` method on it to update the styles and create any
>   nested lists that are added. For example:
>
> ```
> $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
> ```
>
> Note that the `refresh()` method only affects new nodes appended to a
>   list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already
>   enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if
>   you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list
>   item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated,
>   replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Example:

```
// using the id of your <ul> tag
$('#pictures').listview('refresh');
```

UPDATE:

You might also need to refresh the page as well, like this

```
// id="Gallery"
$('#Gallery').trigger('create');
```

Comment: Yes I already added a refresh to the list but It didn't resolve the problem to find the class of the page.

Comment: @michael643 updated my answer to refresh the page jQM controls as well, if this doesn't help could you provide a link to the site?

Comment: Both refresh and trigger create doesn't help. Unfortunately I don't have a link to page because it's an photogap application for android.

Comment: what about the first question I asked you, is it a typo?

Comment: What I found out is that the first time the images will be appened it won't work, but second time (when the images are already append into the page) the images opened nicely in the viewer.
So i think there have to do something of a refresh after I append the images into the page.